# Cannot use try / with blocks inside sequence expressions. How to get around it?

Tags: .net, f#

Consider that

```
Pentagonal numbers are generated by the formula, Pn=n(3n−1)/2.
```

I opted to create a sequence of pentagonal numbers in F#:

```
let pentagonalSeq = { 1..Int32.MaxValue } |> Seq.map (fun n -> n*(3*n-1)/2)
```

So far so good. For most purposes I'll only want to calculate a couple of small integer pentagonal numbers. But there may be times I wish, for instance, to get all `Int32` pentagonal numbers. I was thinking it would be possible to just go on calculating them until I eventually got an `OverflowException` (I'm using checked arithmetic). The trouble is that F# isn't particularly happy about my idea, yelling that

```
'try/with' cannot be used inside sequence expressions
```

What's the best way to keep this young lady satisfied?

Assume that I want to create a `int32_pentagonalSeq` that:

1. makes use of `pentagonalSeq`
2. does not incur in any extra calculations trying to predict whether the next item might or not might not originate an overflow.

Thanks

Comment: Very cool `takeWhileNonException` introduced in Tomas' answer cannot help the defect in `pentagonalSeq`, which overflows prematurely. It can be fixed by changing mapper function to `fun n -> let nL = int64 n in int(nL*(3L*nL-1L)/2L)`.

Comment: I admit the question to be somewhat ill-posed. I don't particularly care about pentagonal overflowing, I care about correctly handling sequences not of my own throwing exceptions. relax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer from Gene is probably the way to go! But if you wanted to use sequence expressions to iterate over elements of a sequence that you already have, you could write something like this:

```
let takeWhileNonException (input:seq<_>) = seq { 
  use ps = input.GetEnumerator()
  while (try ps.MoveNext() with _ -> false) do 
    yield ps.Current }
```

Sadly, you cannot just wrap `for` loop or `yield!` statement with `try` .. `with` because (as you said), sequence expressions does not support exception handlers. However, you can use the underlying iterator and wrap the `MoveNext` call in exception handler (because this is an ordinary expression) and return `false` when the operation fails for the first time.

So, to get the last number of the sequence, you can now write:

```
pentagonalSeq
|> takeWhileNonException
|> Seq.last
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you do something like this maybe?

```
let pentagonal n = 
   try
      Some(n*(3*n-1)/2)
   with
     | ex -> None

let x = { 1.. Int32.MaxValue } |> Seq.map pentagonal
```

Answer (score 2):

You can instead of sequence comprehension use [`Seq.unfold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340363.aspx) with generator function using [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340296.aspx) arithmetic, like in the snippet below:

```
open Checked
let generator n = 
    try
        Some ((n*(3*n-1)/2), n+1)
    with 
       | :? System.OverflowException -> None

let pentagonalSeq = Seq.unfold generator 1
```

Now you can see in FSI what would be the last pentagonal integer that *can be calculated with this formula without overflow*:

```
pentagonalSeq |> Seq.last;;
val it : int = 1073731660
```

Apparently this is not the maximal pentagonal Int32, which is, by the way, 2147438935. However, to calculate pentagonal numbers between 1073731660 and 2147438935 you would need to operate outside of `int` numbers field. This in some sense makes reaching your initial goal even easier, as it does not require checked arithmetic and `try-with` machinery at all:

```
let pentagonalSeq = Seq.unfold
                        (fun n -> let pentagonal = n*(3L*n-1L)/2L in
                                  if pentagonal > (int64 System.Int32.MaxValue) then
                                      None // Sequence is over
                                  else
                                      Some((int pentagonal), n+1L)) // Member and next state
                         1L  // Initial state
```

Checking in FSI again we can see that now it is a genuine `int` sequence of pentagonal numbers, indeed:

```
pentagonalSeq |> Seq.last;;
val it : int = 2147438935
```

Comment: Gene, although you gave a quite interesting answer, it not only fails on point 1) "makes use of pentagonalSeq"as it fails at point 2: "does not incur in any extra calculations trying to predict whether the next item might or not might not originate an overflow.".

Comment: @devouredelysium: Really? (1) I do not use `pentagonalSeq` definition for the good reason - as defined it allows getting only less, than half `Int32` pentagonal numbers, hence cannot be a base for the full sequence; and (2) involving overflows is not a right approach altogether (see (1) for the consequences), so I do not use them at all getting your point 2 fulfilled. The suggested idiomatic approach yielding full sequence of `Int32` pentagonals doesn't look a "double failure" to me, indeed.